# Why is the VBA code not saving individual sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

The code below should save every sheet in my automated file. Why does it save the whole file again and again with sheets(i) simply highlighted?

```
 Sub Splitbook()
        MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
                For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                Sheets(i).Activate
                Sheets(i).SaveAs _
                        Filename:=MyPath & "\" & Sheets(i).Name & ".xlsx"
                        'ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: You cant save sheets, you save the Workbook.

Comment: If you want to save just the sheet you need to copy it to create a new workbook, then save that workbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @braX said -  Each sheet will be saved in a new workbook.
As @TimWilliams said - each sheet needs copying to a new workbook before saving.

`ThisWorkbook` is the file containing the VBA code.
When a worksheet is copied to a new file the new file becomes the active workbook so we can reference it that way (it would be great if we could write `Set wrkBk = wrkSht.Copy`, but VBA doesn't like that).

Once we have a reference to the new file we can save it using the sheet name - you may want to add code that ensures the sheet name is a viable file name.

```
Public Sub SplitWorkbook()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wrkSht.Copy
        Set wrkBk = ActiveWorkbook
        'Save the new file without closing.
        'wrkBk.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wrkBk.Worksheets(1).Name

        'Save the new file and close.
        wrkBk.Close True, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wrkBk.Worksheets(1).Name
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: This works only partially. The code I have written before this sub doesn't run anymore, so in the end it splits the sheets in a raw form. What I need is an external macro that acts upon an xlsx file.

Comment: UPDATE: I found the mistake I had. It works even with the macro in the report. I just forgot to activate the first sheet :-)